# After install cocoapods (pod install) in xcode 7.x breakpoint is not working

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods, breakpoints

I have xcode 7.2.1 version after installing  cocoapods breakpoint is not working. If i create new project for that breakpoint is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode might get messed up.

First clean the project, then run it!

Comment: I have did that and also ALT+Clean. Uninstall xCode and tried but no luck.